# Error while downloading mysql api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Tags: mysql, windows, operating-system

I am trying to install MySQL database getting api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll error I downloaded and replaced the file but unable to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error basically is telling you that the `dll`, namely, `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`, is not available on the PC. This DLL is usually not installed alongside the software program that throws the error.

To get to the root of your problem, first understand what causes it, i.e., which the particular DLL is that it's not able to find. This DLL, `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll`, is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.

Hence as a first go try reinstalling the **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable**. This should register the missing `.dll` file in your PC.

For further details and info, you can refer to [this guide](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/06/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing/) to solving the problem.

Quite in contrast to what your error says, reinstalling the program doesn't actually fix the problem. And more importantly, not all `missing dll` errors are solved by just downloading and placing the `dll`s in the file system. Try as much as possible to NOT do this. if you're wondering why, [check this out](https://www.lifewire.com/important-reasons-not-to-download-dll-files-2624455).

Answer (score 0):

`api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` is an important file that is required to run such specific type of programs on Windows. If you're facing this issue, then it means this file is missing from your computer.

So, in order to run your desired program, you will need to fix the .dll error. There are a number of ways using which you can solve this problem. The three main solutions are:

1. UPDATE THE WINDOWS
2. REPAIR VISUAL C++ REDISTRIBUTABLE FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2015
3. DOWNLOAD & INSTALL VISUAL C++ REDISTRIBUTABLE FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2015 MANUALLY

So, you can fix [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing error](https://www.intenseclick.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-error/) using the above ways.

Thanks,
Eric